# Re-asking with a larger bounty when one expires

Tags: discussion, bounty

I assigned a bounty to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920299/handling-invalid-jsonp-requests-in-web-api), which expired without getting any answer.

I want to re-launch it with a larger bounty.

How can I do that?

Comment: Wait until the current bounty has ended, then start again

Comment: If you want, ping me once there's a "start bounty" link visible again and I can place the bounty, I'm always looking for good questions to put bounties on. No point for a member in apparently good standing to lose their closevote rights again

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, I thought when it said my bounty expired it meant that it ended. I didn't know there was something else to happen after it.

Comment: The question _could_ use an example API, a model, some example data and some input/output traffic (captured with Fiddler) so people willing to help reproduce and fix the issue can jump-start their environment. Just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is currently in the grace period. This is an extra 24 hours during which the bounty can be awarded... if an answer is given.

Once these 24 hours are over, you can start a new bounty. It must, however, be at least twice the value of the current bounty, to a maximum of 500.
In your case, the current bounty is 50 points, so a new bounty should be at least 100 points.